# Update minimum API level for Android app, can they still do in app purchase?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play-services

Currently the minimum API level of my Android app is 16. But I want to update this to a minimum of API level 17. What happens to the user (with API level 16) that allready have my App? They can't update it? Can they still do in app purchase?
I guess user with API 16 that don't have the App can't find it in the Playstore anymore?

Thank you:)

Answer (score 1):

1. The users, who are already using your app and have API 16 will continue using this version of your app
2. New users with API 16 won't be able to install your app, if you deactivate previous version APK from play store. If you won't deactivate it, new users would be able to install and use old version.
3. (*Here comes staff, I'm not sure.*) If you deactivate your old APK, users with API 16, who already are using your app won't be able to use in-app purchases, since the APK, they are trying to purchase with is not supported anymore.
4. If you **don't** deactivate your old APK, users with API 16, who already are using your app, and new users with API 16 **will** be able to use in-app purchases.